# VS 2013 SSAS Multi Dimensional project drill down sheet in excel ignores formatting

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio-2013, ssas, business-intelligence

I searched around for this but couldn't find an answer. I think it'll be best explained with some images. I have created a multi dimensional project in VS 2013 using sql BI data tools. I connect to it from excel and everything displays fine, all the measures work, drilldowns work, etc. One problem I have though is that when a 'total' cell is double clicked on, excel opens a new sheet and shows the drilldown data but the data has no formatting. 'Date To' column is displayed as '41516'. When I format the cell in excel as date then it shows the value in correct format. I have set the measure's format in the project but they don't seem to have any effect. I haven't created any drilldown actions in VS, double click is the default drill down. But that shouldn't matter as you can only select the data when you create an action, not the formatting. The formatting applies when the same measure is shown on the main sheet though but not in drill down. Any ideas how to format the values in drill down sheet?

Measures:

[image]

Format strings for the 'Date To' measure:

[image]

Drill down in excel:

[image]

Comment: I also tried "Inherit" for `DataType` but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a comment (rather than an answer).

@Mike is correct...no need to have it in the measure group, just create a custom drillthrough action and specify the date dimension attribute. If you use a properly formatted column for the Name property of that attribute, then the formatting should propagate through (didn't know this for sure so tested it out below)

**** **Before:** ******************************************

[image]
[image]

**** **After:** ******************************************

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Bill. I'll have to check this tomorrow at work and maybe I'm missing something but if I add "ToDate" as a dimension attribute, won't "ToDate" show up on the main sheet in excel as a checkbox attribute? I don't want to show "ToDate" on the main sheet but only on the drill down. As far as I know once it's added as an attribute to the dimension, it gets displayed on the main sheet, as dimension attribute doesn't have "visibility" property.

Comment: should be able to set the AttributeHierachyVisibility to False. This can be done at the SSAS-database level (so that the effect applies to all instances of the dimension used in all cubes) or at the individual SSAS-cube level (so that the effect applies to a single instance ("role") of that dimension)

Answer (score 4):

I would change "Date To" from a Measure to a Dimension Attribute.  Then you can use the Date column for the KeyColumns property and a formatted string column for the NameColumn property.

Dates dont make any sense to me as Measures.

Comment: Thanks Mike. The cube displays employee leaves, long service leave, annual leave, etc. I have "FromDate" in a dimension but the client wants to see "ToDate" only on the drill down in excel. That's why I have created it as a measure, because I can make it invisible, so they don't see it on the excel main sheet, but it displays on the drill down.

Comment: @artm - you can make the "ToDate" a dimension attribute and set its visibility so it doesn't show up in the PT-field explorer, but is still accessible in the custom drillthrough action.